# How do you send a PINGREQ in python for paho mqtt?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I connect to my mosquitto broker with

```
client.connect("192.168.1.1",1883,60)
```

to establish the connection, and the server expects traffic every 60 seconds. The paho documentation refers to a PINGREQ/PINGACK message which I would like to use to keep the connection alive.

Can't find any examples of this  - how to do this in python (2.7)?

Comment: SHOW ALL YOUR CODE

Comment: This post came from a misunderstanding of how the network loop manages the connection behind the scenes. I was running MQTT client code from a python prompt, outside my normal scripts that do have threaded loops for receiving pubs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you don't

The pings are handled by the MQTT Client [network loop](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#network-loop). You need to start this after connecting. There are 3 ways to run the loop:

1. `client.start_loop()` This starts the network loop on a background thread
2. `client.loop_forever()` This starts the  network loop on the current thread and will block forever.
3. `client.loop()` this executes one cycle of the network loop and must be called as part of your own loop.